# Can I get average of a column in mySQL DB based upon value of other column in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot, average

I have a table of phone call activity for a client. In the table, I have one column for the length of the call (in seconds), and another column for "first time call" (true / false). I was hoping to find a way to get the average call length of first time calls separated from the average time of non first time calls? Is this doable in a singe mySQL query?

```
SELECT location,
    count(*) AS total,
    sum(case when firstCall = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) AS firstCall,
    sum(case when answered = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS answered,
    sum(case when tags like '%Lead%' then 1 else 0 end) as lead,
    sum(case when tags like '%arbage%' then 1 else 0 end) as garbage,    
    avg(case when duration........firstTime = True???)
FROM staging
GROUP BY location
```

Comment: `SELECT location, firstCall, AVG(duration) ... GROUP BY location, firstCall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT location,
count(*) AS total,
sum(case when firstCall = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) AS firstCall,
sum(case when answered = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS answered,
sum(case when tags like '%Lead%' then 1 else 0 end) as lead,
sum(case when tags like '%arbage%' then 1 else 0 end) as garbage,    
sum(case when firstCall='true' then duration else 0 end)/sum(case when firstCall =     'true' then 1 else 0 end) as first_call_true_average,
sum(case when firstCall='false' then duration else 0 end)/sum(case when firstCall  = 'false' then 1 else 0 end) as first_call_false_average

 FROM staging
 GROUP BY location
```

Comment: 'end' was corrupted from case when statement , I updated answer

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so very, very much. is it possible to return those values rounded up so there are not decimals? Such as 211.7895 would be 211 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as:

```
select 
    location,
    count(*) as total,
    sum(firstcall = 'true'  ) as cnt_firstcall,
    sum(answered = 'Yes'    ) as cnt_answered,
    sum(tags like '%Lead%'  ) as cnt_lead,
    sum(tags like '%arbage%') as cnt_garbage,    
    avg(case when firstcall = 'true'  then duration end) as avg_first_call,_duration
    avg(case when firstcall = 'false' then duration end) as avg_non_first_call_duration
from staging
group by location
```

Rationale:

- MySQL interpret true/false conditions as 1/0 values in numeric context, which greatly shortens the conditional `sum()`s
- `avg()` ignores `null` values, so a simple `case` expression is sufficient to compute the conditional averages

Comment: Thank you for this follow up. I am a bit new to Stack Overflow and not sure how to attribute the "answer" to a question. I previously marked the other person as answered but if yours is a better solution would I change that attribution?

Comment: @TomHall: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335658/if-my-questions-accepted-answer-is-no-longer-the-best-should-i-change-the-acce and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @TomHall: your expression looks fine.